# Tablesorter detect changes or on change?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am having trouble finding out how to do the following:

I want a counter at the top with the number of rows displayed and the number of total rows like this:

`10/100` (Not a pager)

What do I trigger on?

I have a variable on `$(document).ready()` like this: `var total = $('table').length;`
How do I trigger the current rows on a filter change?

I am using the [tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) plugin.

Comment: Used to play with tablesorter quite a bit.... but didn't know there was any filter mechanism....just sorting. That plugin hasn't been actively developed or supported for years. Create a demo of your configuration in jsfiddle.net

Comment: @charlietfl I've forked [tablesorter on github](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) with lots of fixes and improvements :)

Comment: @Mottie my bad then about not actively developed... good on you! I spent a lot of time in jQuery forum over the years....project was pretty dormant for a long, long time...my bet is 6 or 7 years

Comment: @charlietfl Well, I've been trying to keep it up-to-date! I plan to make version 3 modularized and everything will be a widget, even sorting! :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/1493/)), it uses the [`filterEnd` event](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#filterend) to update the row count display:

```
var $count = $('.count'),
    $t = $('table'),
    $tr = $t.find('tbody tr'),
    update = function(){
        var t = $tr.filter(':visible').length + '/' + $tr.length;
        $count.html(t);
    };

$t
    .on('filterEnd', function () {
        update();
    })
    .tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
        initialized: function(){
            update();
        }
    });
```